# Removing nested html element in a string

Tags: php, jquery, html, regex, string

I am using an API to retrieve the HTML for all webforms inside of a certain application. The trouble is that the returned HTML contains `<html>`, `<style>`, and `<body>` tags around the `<form>`, but all I need is the `<form>` (there is also an `onsubmit` attribute, but I am fairly sure I can handle that a little bit down the road).

I was able to remove the style tags with some clever regex, but I am unsure of a way to remove the `<form>` from the middle of the `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

So far this is all happening in PHP. I am thinking it might be possible to `json_encode` the string and then pass it over to JS and use jQuery to `getJSON` maybe? I'm still not 100% clear on the best way to do this though.

Sample of my returned php string...

```
<html width="100%" height="100%">
  <body class="body stuff">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="input">
      <input type="text" name="anotherInput">
    </form>
  </body>
</form>
```

All I want out of this string is the `<form>` though

Comment: Have you tried using `DOMDocument`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?
$regex = "/<form>(.*?)<\/form>/s";
preg_match($regex,$string,$match);
print_r($match);
?>
```

should result in something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <form>
      <input type="text" name="input">
      <input type="text" name="anotherInput">
    </form>
    [1] => 
      <input type="text" name="input">
      <input type="text" name="anotherInput">

)
```

what you need then would be `$match[1]`

Comment: I had to modify the regex a little bit because of some extra attributes on the form tags themselves `"/<form (.*?)>(.*?)<\/form>/is"`, but this ended up working perfectly. thanks! I also had to use `preg_match_all` for some reason, which I don't completely understand

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to convert your string to a DOM Object.

Then append or use [DOM traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to find whatever objects you need. Additionally when you use [$.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) it appears to remove the `<html>` and `<body>` tags automatically, leaving only the innards of the document.

```
var string = '<html width="100%" height="100%"><body class="body stuff"><form><input type="text" name="input"><input type="text" name="anotherInput"></form></body></html>';

var htmlObject = $.parseHTML(string);
$('body').append( htmlObject );
```

Here is a quick [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tb67ez75/2/) I put together.

**Edit**

In the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tb67ez75/2/) you can see an [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method loop through the object and append the `nodenames` to an unordered list. This is how you can verify that [$.parseHTML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) actually removed the `<html>` and `<body>` from the object.